# RecyclerView + Glide shows result in a mess

Tags: android, android-listview, picasso, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm using recyclerView and Glide to implement a horizontal gallery, and here is the main code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onListItemClick(v, position);
            }
        });
    }
    Firmware.VideoModel videoModel = mDataList.get(position);
    String url = videoModel.getPreurl();
    if (position == 0) {
        holder.mImageView.setPadding(mCtx.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin) - mCtx.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.image_margin), holder.mImageView.getPaddingTop(), holder.mImageView.getPaddingRight(), holder.mImageView.getPaddingBottom());
    } else if (mDataList != null && position == mDataList.size() - 1) {
        holder.mImageView.setPadding(holder.mImageView.getPaddingLeft(), holder.mImageView.getPaddingTop(), mCtx.getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin), holder.mImageView.getPaddingBottom());
    }
    if (mDataList != null && mDataList.size() >= 0) {
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).error(R.drawable.image_placeholder).into(holder.mImageView);
        if (videoModel.isVideo()) {
            holder.mImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.mImageButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set a space padding to the first and the last image so I can scroll all of the images into the screen edge, just like the Google Play.

Sadly here is the problem:

As recyclerView will recycle views those are not in the visible area, the paddings I set will be in a mess as I scroll this recyclerView left and right. The padding will be added to the second, even the third or any other image if the position's view was recycled...

I've stackoverflowd the answer, one of them is to call:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
```

This really works. But that will be meaningless to use a RecyclerView right? So I hope someone can help me. Thx.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similiar issue with Glide but I'm not changing padding nor anything view related. It's a mess, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not change padding dynamically instead of it you should use few different types of ViewHolders(with different layouts) or custom LayoutManager for your needs.